# Does gmail addon support jquery/angularjs?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an addon in my gmail. I was wondering whether it supports jquery/angularjs etc., Or it's just only plain javascript.

How can we achieve **deferred** concept in gmail addon?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you wanted to know could have been found out in a simple google search. http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/
This link will be able to answer both of your questions.

TL:DR

It has a javascript library and an early stage node.js (alpha) library

**EDIT:** As stated above the two main supported libraries which i feel would be of use to you are a javascript and node.js library. The other libraries are as follows: Java, Python, PHP (Beta), .NET, Objective-C, Dart(Beta), Ruby (Alpha) and finally Go (Alpha).

You enquire about whether it has Angular support although not officially supported you can find an angular-google-gapi on github that:

> An AngularJS module for using all Google Apis and your Google Cloud
>   Endpoints (Google App Engine) with OAuth. This module uses Google APIs
>   Client Library for JavaScript, available for all GApis.

it was created by the github user maximepvrt and is available here: https://github.com/maximepvrt/angular-google-gapi

This might be what you are looking for.